# Completeness Axiom and Two Mutually Exclusive Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: (Completeness Axiom): No closed intervals is the union of two mutually exclusive closed point sets.

Proof:

Let ${T}$ = [${a_T}$,${b_T}$] and let $S$ = [$a_S$,$b_S$] such that that are mutually exclusive

Then $T$ and $S$ have no points in common

Because $T$ and $S$ are closed intervals, they each have a left-most and right-most points, which are the endpoints

Let $p$ $\in$ $T$ s.t. $p$ is between two other points $r$ and $u$ of $S$

Then there is a point $q$ between $r$ and $q$ and between $q$ and $u$

$\therefore$ $T$$\cup$$S$ is not a closed interval

If $T$$\lt$$S$ then there exists some $p_n$ between the right-most point of $T$ and the left-most point of $S$ where $p_n$$\notin$$T$$\cup$$S$

Is this a sufficient proof? What improvements could I make to make this better?

Comment: What if no such $p \in T$ exists?

Comment: Closed point sets do not necessarily mean closed intervals. You have to just assume that $S, T$ are closed sets and begin with the assumption that $[a, b] =S\cup T, S\cap T=\emptyset, S\neq\emptyset,T\neq \emptyset $ and derive a contradiction.